# Convert String to int in Service

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to convert `String` into `integer`. `Integer.parseInt()` worked before, but now it is failing. It is failing here   `int INTERVAL=  (60000 * Integer.parseInt(preferenceTime));` I am trying dynamically specify time when I schedule a timer.
thank you

```
public class Service extends Service {

    public SharedPreferences settings;


    private Handler HandleIt = new Handler();
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    boolean timeout = false;
    //private PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);





    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////

    class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {



        @Override
        public void run() {
            HandleIt.post(new Runnable(){
               public void run(){

                   //SharedPreferences
                   settings = getSharedPreferences("timer_preference", MODE_PRIVATE);
                   String preferenceTime = settings.getString("timer_preference", "");

                  // int INTERVAL=  (60000 * Integer.parseInt(preferenceTime));


                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), TextonScreen(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                   //get screen light up
                   PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                   boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
                   if(isScreenOn==false) {
                       pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK |  PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "My Tag");
                   }
                   // make a new intent and start it with flag   and send an sms
                   Intent launch = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SMS.class);
                   launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                   startActivity(launch);
               }
            });
        }


    }

    private String TextonScreen()
    {
        timeout = true;
        return "it is running";


    }
    boolean isTimeout()
    {
        return timeout;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service is created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences( getPackageName() + "timer_preference", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String preferenceTime = settings.getString("timer_preference", "");
        int INTERVAL=  (60000 * Integer.parseInt(preferenceTime));



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Display the Toast Message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Start Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Execute an action after period time
        //comes from the TimeDisplayTimerTask class
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, INTERVAL);


        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Display the Toast Message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Stop Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean - failing? Do you get an error? Unexpected result?

Comment: What do mean by failing? Is it throwing any exception?

Comment: when I build an Apk and install it on the phone. and try to launch it.  it says "unfortunately, application has stopped."  if I will comment integer.parseint() out it runs well.

Comment: Run the app when your device is connected to your PC and check the logcat's output. You'll see the exact error there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse it would fail because you want to parser "" as an int !
Try this :

```
String preferenceTime = settings.getString("timer_preference", "0");
int INTERVAL=  (60000 * Integer.parseInt(preferenceTime));
```

`0` means if i never set anything in it, return 0. Its the default value.

why aren't you storing it as an int ?! i mean this :

```
int preferenceTime = settings.getInteger("timer_preference", 0);
int INTERVAL=  (60000 * preferenceTime);
```

Comment: The reason I am not storing it as int is that it is Listpreference. it was giving me an error. It worked thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If it fails to parse a number, it will throw a NumberFormatException. I usually like to wrap `Integer#parseInt` calls in an `Optional` so I can supply a default value:

```
public static Optional<Integer> parseInt(String s) {
    try {
        return Optional.of(Integer.parseInt(s));
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Then, calling can supply a default (or let you know it failed via `#isPresent` returning `false`):

```
int value = parseInt(preferenceTime).orElse(/* some default integer */);
```

Comment: Yup, but you can easily just add an argument and pass the default yourself. The main point is a failed parse throws a `NumberFormatException`